# use lodash convert one JSON structure to another

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a json JSON structure like this

```
var data = [
      {
        "S1": "$13",
        "S3B/T1": "$15",
        "S3B-N/SS-GG": "$17",
        "S3B-BN/SF-SS/GF-GG": "$18",
        "WDA/WDB": "$15",
        "WDA-CT/WDB-CT": "$18"
      },
      {
        "S1": "$20",
        "S3B/T1": "$23",
        "S3B-N/SS-GG": "$26",
        "S3B-BN/SF-SS/GF-GG": "$27",
        "WDA/WDB": "$23",
        "WDA-CT/WDB-CT": "$27"
      }
    ];
```

I want to convert data to an output structure like this.
Here's the target with just the result I want to achieve.

```
    var data = [
        {
          "S1": "$13",
          "S3B": "$15",
          "T1": "$15"
          "S3B-N": "$17",
          "SS-GG": "$17",
          "S3B-BN": "$18",
          "SF-SS": "$18",
          "GF-GG": "$18",
          "WDA": "$15",
          "WDB": "$15",
          "WDA-CT": "$18",
          "WDB-CT": "$18"
        },
        {
          "S1": "$20",
          "S3B": "$23",
          "T1": "$23",
          "S3B-N": "$26",
          "SS-GG": "$26",
          "S3B-BN": "$27",
          "SF-SS": "$27",
          "GF-GG": "$27",
          "WDA": "$23",
          "WDB": "$23",
          "WDA-CT": "$27",
          "WDB-CT": "$27"
        }
    ]
```

split the key valeu to new object if the value is the same.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may achieve the desired transformation with [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [spread operator for object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). No lodash is needed.

```js
data.map(item =>
  Object.entries(item).reduce((acc, [key, val]) => ({
    ...acc,
    ...key.split('/').reduce((_acc, _key) => ({
      ..._acc,
      [_key]: val
    }), {})
  }), {})
);
```

- `map` iterates through the top-level array (data)
- 1st `reduce` iterates through the properties of the item-object of `data` and accumulates new object
- each key of the item-object is being transformed into an array via splitting by `/` symbol
- and that sub-array is being accumulated into another object (via 2nd `reduce`) that would have sub-keys which would keep a single value corresponded to the original key

Comment: thanks for your explain dhilt.
because the project can not use es6 spread operator, how about use lodash to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

```
        _.map(data, function(v){
        return _.keys(v).reduce(function(acc, key){
            var val = v[key];
            var innerObj = key.split('/').reduce(function(_acc, _key){
                return _.merge(_acc, {[_key]: val});
            },{});
            return _.merge(acc, innerObj)
        },{})
    });
```

I use lodash based on @dhilt answer. thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Vanilla JS** - Iterate the array with `Array.map()`. Take the entries (`[key, value]` pairs) of each object, and iterate them with `Array.flatMap()`. Split each key by `/`, iterate the parts with `Array.map()` and return a [part, value] pair. Convert back to an object with `Object.fromEntries()`:

```js
const data = [{"S1":"$13","S3B/T1":"$15","S3B-N/SS-GG":"$17","S3B-BN/SF-SS/GF-GG":"$18","WDA/WDB":"$15","WDA-CT/WDB-CT":"$18"},{"S1":"$20","S3B/T1":"$23","S3B-N/SS-GG":"$26","S3B-BN/SF-SS/GF-GG":"$27","WDA/WDB":"$23","WDA-CT/WDB-CT":"$27"}]

const result = data.map(
  o => Object.fromEntries( // convert the arrays of pairs back to an object
    Object.entries(o) // get pairs of [key, val]
      .flatMap(([key, val]) => // map the pairs and flatten the sub-arrays
        key.split('/').map(k => [k, val]) // split the key and map each part to pair of [k, val]
      )
  )
)

console.log(result)
```

**Lodash** - Iterate the array with `Array.map()`. Iterate each object with `_.flatMap()`. Split each key by `/`, iterate the parts with `Array.map()` and return a [part, value] pair. Convert back to an object with `_.fromPairs()`:

```js
const data = [{"S1":"$13","S3B/T1":"$15","S3B-N/SS-GG":"$17","S3B-BN/SF-SS/GF-GG":"$18","WDA/WDB":"$15","WDA-CT/WDB-CT":"$18"},{"S1":"$20","S3B/T1":"$23","S3B-N/SS-GG":"$26","S3B-BN/SF-SS/GF-GG":"$27","WDA/WDB":"$23","WDA-CT/WDB-CT":"$27"}]

const result = data.map(
  o => _.fromPairs( // convert the arrays of pairs back to an object
      _.flatMap(o, (val, key) => // map the objects' properties and flatten the sub-arrays
        key.split('/').map(k => [k, val]) // split the key and map each part to pair of [k, val]
      )
  )
)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Welcome. I've added a lodash solution as well.